# sharedPreferences in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, sharedpreferences

I know this has been asked before, but i can't seem to figure it out

i am trying to get my preferences by this:

```
SharedPreferences preferences = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("storedName",     Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String loginemail = preferences.getString("storedName", "");
```

but this doesn't seem to work, i have multiple sharedPreferences which i need to get in my fragment what is the correct way to do it?
As `getDefaulSharedPreferences(this)` doesn't work.

i store my prefs like so:

```
savePreferences("shareUniqePass", uniqePassIds.getText().toString());
savePreferences("storedName", inputEmail.getText().toString());
savePreferences("Storedpass", inputPassword.getText().toString());

private void savePreferences(String key, boolean value){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    Editor checkbox = sharedPreferences.edit();
    checkbox.putBoolean(key, value);
    checkbox.commit();
}
private void savePreferences(String key, String value){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    Editor names = sharedPreferences.edit();
    names.putString(key, value);
    names.commit();
}
```

Comment: post savePreferences method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of getting it from `getSharedPreferences` use the `getDefaultSharedPreferences`.

```
As getDefaulSharedPreferences(this) doesn't work.
```

You used `getDefaultSharedPreferences` for saving the data and therefore you must use `getDefaultSharedPreferences` to get the data that was saved.

`this` mean the instance of your fragment instead use the `getActivity()` to get the instance of context from your activity.

**sample:**

```
String loginemail = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity()).getString(PREF_USER_NAME, "");;
```

Comment: Thanks this helped, However is this also the best way? or should i save them a other way? in some sort of object? for best coding i mean

Comment: @user3671459 that is the best way, because you cant put object to the getSharedPreferences. You are welcome +1 this post if it helps.. thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that your saving and loading the data from the same shared preferences. If you're only accessing it from the one activity / fragment, you should use `getDefaulSharedPreferences(this)`.

If, however, you're going to use it from several different activities / fragments, you should use:

```
private void savePreferences(String key, boolean value){
    SharedPreferences prefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("storedName", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    Editor checkbox = sharedPreferences.edit();
    checkbox.putBoolean(key, value);
    checkbox.commit();
}
```